# How to extract data from one file based on the IDs for another

Tags: r, keras, bioinformatics

I am running code where I take one gene from a gene list, find it's Sentinel gene in Data1, and then select all rows with a matching rssnp1 ID to the gene at it's Sentinel row. However, currently my code runs this at only one gene at a time, I am trying to run it so it will iterate through each gene in my gene list in Data2, creating either 1 file with all outputs in or individual files per gene.

My data looks like this:

Data1 (filename: loci):

```
Chr  Start   End     rssnp1        Type    gene
1   1244733 1244734 rs2286773   LD_SNP  ACE
1   1257536 1257436 rs301159    LD_SNP  CPEB4
1   1252336 1252336 rs2286773   Sentinel    CPEB4
1   1252343 1252343 rs301159    LD_SNP  CPEB4
1   1254841 1254841 rs301159    LD_SNP  CPEB4
1   1256703 1267404 rs301159    LD_SNP  CPEB4
1   1269246 1269246 rs301159    LD_SNP  CPEB4
1   1370168 1370168 rs301159    LD_SNP  GLUPA1
1   1371824 1371824 rs301159    LD_SNP  GLUPA1
1   1372591 1372591 rs301159    LD_SNP  GLUPA1
```

Data2 (filename: genelist):

```
    gene
    CPEB4
    GML
    TBX2
    PNKD
    JMJD1C
    SKI
    MYH11
    ACE
```

I also have a 3rd data file which is the class the gene was predicted as with keras machine learning (a column of labels 0-3 for each gene), and I append this column after extracting the data for the genes at that rssnp1 location.

Data3 (filename: keraspredictions)

```
    gene        keras.prediction
    CPEB4          2
    GML            1 
    TBX2           1
    PNKD           3
    JMJD1C         0
    SKI            1
    MYH11          2
     ACE           1
```

With this I am trying:

```
loci <-read.csv('genelocifilter.csv') #Data1
geneslist <-read.csv('genelist.csv')  #Data2
keras <-read.csv('Keraspredictions.csv')  #Machine learning prediction

getFromData1 <- function(geneFromData2 = NULL) {
     if (is.null(geneFromData2)) return()
      geneSentinelSNP <- (loci %>% filter(Type == "Sentinel" & gene == geneFromData2))$rssnp1
      loci %>% filter(rssnp1 == geneSentinelSNP)
  } 

gene <- getFromData1(geneFromData2 = "CPEB4")
#if error here Type == Sentinel needs to be LD_SNP

gene_class <- left_join(gene, keras %>% select(gene, Keras.prediction) , by = "gene")

write.csv(gene_class, "./CPEB4.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

This works to output:

```
Chr Start   End   rssnp1        Type    gene      Keras.prediction
1   1244733 1244734 rs2286773   LD_SNP  ACE             1

1   1252336 1252336 rs2286773   Sentinel    CPEB4       2
```

How can I make this iterate over each gene as opposed to 1 at a time that I am naming manually? I am a beginner so I am not sure where to start with making a for loop for this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not very clear, could you provide example rows from `loci`, `geneslist`, `keras` dataframes.... and expected output for these rows.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have added in that data1 and data2 are loci and genelist, and added what the keras file also looks like. The output is at the bottom, and is exactly what I want to get but with iterative code doing every gene in 1 go as opposed to 1 at a time as I am currently doing with manually writing in CPEB4.

Comment: Why in the output for ACE keras.prediction is 1, not NA?

Comment: Apologies, I've made these datasets for the sake of example and missed ACE - it's there now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
#using your custom function and dplyr
library(dplyr)

lapply(geneslist$gene, function(i){
  gene <- getFromData1(geneFromData2 = i)
  left_join(gene, keras %>% select(gene, Keras.prediction) , by = "gene")
})
```

But there must be easier way just by merging, e.g.:

```
# using just merge
SentinelSNPs <- unique(loci[ loci$Type == "Sentinel", "rssnp1"])
merge(loci[ loci$rssnp1 %in% SentinelSNPs, ], keras, by = "gene", all.x = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, merging has almost worked for me but it gives the list with all the genes inthe alphabetical order, but I need the rssnp1 ID to be in order of matching IDs grouped together, would there be a step I could add after merging to achieve this?

Comment: Then you can order using `order`, something like `myResult <- myResult[ order(myResult$rssnp1), ]`